# cookies's class definition in rails hierarchy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm practicing in rails programming. 
one question that I have in mind at the moment is as follows.

Regarding the code below, I can get a reference to the cookies class in a helper module I recently created. My question is where in rails class hierarchy the cookies class is defined?

I just need to get better understanding about its class hierarchy design and why it's automatically available to the helper class.

my code snippet is provided as below: (This is from Michael Hartl's rails tutorial chapter 9)

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end
end
```

any advice would be really much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In action_dispatch and is wrapped in ActionController

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Cookies

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I get a better understanding now. anyhow, are all helper classes actually defined in ActionController::Helpers (as in     http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers)